# Setting the user agent in Firefox using geckodriver v0.11

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am working on updating our selenium tests to function with Firefox v50.x and thus I need to make them compatible with geckodriver v0.11

It seems now that now initializing the webdriver using a Firefox::Profile makes the webdriver crash as it does not recognize any of the fields set in the profile:

```
ArgumentError
unknown option: {:profile=>#<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile:0x00000005088bf8 @model="selenium_profile", @native_events=false, @secure_ssl=false, @untrusted_issuer=true, @load_no_focus_lib=false, @additional_prefs={}, @extensions={}>}
```

I can still make the tests run by just not initializing the webdriver with a profile, but some of our tests will then fail as they require that we have a specific user agent.

After reading the documentation it seems that you should now use moz:firefoxOptions for this functionality, but I can't find any code examples showing how do actually use moz:firefoxoptions for anything

Could anyone give me a code example showing how to use moz:firefoxOptions or any other way of setting the firefox user agent with selenium-webdriver 3.0.3 and geckodriver v0.11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you cannot currently pass a profile via the profile option for geckodriver. This is documented in [Issue #2933](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2933), and I currently have a PR ([PR #3174](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/3174)) in for adding this functionality.

For now, you should be able to do the following:

Create the profile by either

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new('/path/to/profile')
```

or

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name('name_of_profile')
```

then

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::W3CCapabilities.firefox
caps[:firefox_options] = { profile: profile.as_json['zip'] }
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, desired_capabilities: caps)
```

`[:firefox_options]` gets translated to `moz:firefoxOptions` in the code

On a side note, you could also run with the legacy FF driver instead of geckodriver since you are running against FF50

Comment: Thanks! It's sort of a hassle having to create several profiles in firefox for the different user agents we wish to use, but it seems like this works